# Problem in understanding of a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

> The results showed that a better tip shape **produced** better torque
>   to thrust ratios **in both** forces and moments is a geometry that has
>   the end tip at the pitch axis.

I don't know the meaning of this "produced" and " in both" I know the meaning of each word but I have problem in the meaning of whole sentence.

Comment: What is the source? There is a grammar problem using "is", but it is hard to decipher what the real meaning of your example should be. As for the words in bold, *produced* means *resulted in*, *in* is a preposition, and *both* indicates two of two items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have problems, too, and it's because the sentence is worded in a way that doesn't make sense.

I assume that the sentence is trying to describe what the better tip shape is (a geometry that has the end tip at the pitch axis). In this case, the sentence could be rewritten in the following ways:

> The results showed that a tip shape **that produces** better torque-to-thrust ratios in both forces and moments **involves** a geometry that has the end tip at the pitch axis.
>
> The results showed that, **to produce** better torque-to-thrust ratios in both forces and moments, a better tip shape **is required, which involves** a geometry that has the end tip at the pitch axis.